# How do you deal with the bug where all people die after 5 minutes in Battle for Middle Earth 1?

Tags: battle-for-middle-earth

I'm owning the game Battle for Middle Earth lotr and have completed quite a few missions. Then I installed a few demos such as Trine and a few others. BFME stopped launching now.

So I uninstalled the other games and had to reinstall BFME. Now the game launches fine but after 5 minutes of play everyone dies. I read somewhere that this is on pirated games but I have the @#$ing discs.

Does anyone know how we can get past this problem?

Comment: Have you uninstalled the game before reinstalling? This seems like a copy protection scheme triggering to prevent multiple installs.

Comment: If you own the discs, a quick call to the publisher's support line would probably prove fruitful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh Actually I got this problem solved. I figured the problem must be due to securom because I think that is what was responsible for the problems. So here is what worked:

1. Uninstall lotr
2. Uninstall securom using the uninstaller from their website
3. Reinstall lotr
4. At ease :)

Comment: From games editors: "Enjoy our new anti-piracy protections! They won't disrupt your gaming experience, since your a legit user!"... Then everybody rips those kind of game since protections are kind of a nuisance, but just for the poor legit users... :p

Comment: @Lysarion Ha ha. Thats true.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer because it worked for me. Wish I could upvote this too.